# javascript function on data from flask

Tags: flask

I am working on a feedback function and trying to pass data (list of integers) from FLASk to javaScript but there seems to a missing which I can not figure out. if someone helps me it would be great
->I also read similar posts but most of the datatypes were url or dictionary and not integers.
here is where I have problems with the code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask (__name__)
@app.route('/new')
def new() :
    valu=[10,0,0,10,0,10,0]
    return render_template('feedback.html', value=valu)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)   

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
     <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Feedback page</title>        
     </head>
     <body>
        <script> document.write(value);</script>
     </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are not rendering your jinja template variable correctly for "value" in your javascript line. Should be something like:

```
<script>document.write({{ value }});</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I totally forgot the it